Rationalize the denominator: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$

Rationalize the denominator: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$

My solution:
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{x^2} \Rightarrow \dfrac{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{x^2}=x^{\frac{2}{3}-\frac{6}{3}}=x^{-\frac{4}{3}}$
Book solution: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x} \Rightarrow \dfrac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x}=x^{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{3}{3}}=x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$
Both my solution and the book solution look correct to me, yet $x^{-\frac{4}{3}} \neq x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$. But where is the mistake?

What a fuzz in the first equality? How can $\sqrt[3]{x^2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{x^2}=x^2$? While it should be $(\sqrt[3]{x^2})^2=\sqrt[3]{x^4}=x^{\frac43}$.

$$\dfrac{1}{\color{purple}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\color{red}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\color{green}{x^2}}
$$
Can you explain how did this happen $?$
Edit 
It should be equal to $x^{\frac43}$ and not $x^2$

Well I thought $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2$, so naturally if the radicals have the same root than the answer would just be what's in the radical?

@ronaldchristenkkson: $\sqrt[3]{\ }$ is defined by the following rule: $\sqrt[3]a\cdot\sqrt[3]a\cdot\sqrt[3]a=a$.

Oh my God... so if the radicals have the same root, than the answer is the same only when there is a numerically equivalent number of terms equal to the root. Wow I did not know this!
